# UBUNTU: Installation Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: ubuntu, extjs, installation

I'm rather new to Ubuntu and Linux based Operating Systems, but I need to install Sencha Complete.  I've downloaded the file but I've never seen a *.run file before and I'm not exactly familiar with the Ubuntu command line.

I tried;
`./SenchaCompleteTrial-1.0.5.1-linux-x64.run`
`.SenchaCompleteTrial-1.0.5.1-linux-x64.run`
`sudo sh SenchaCompleteTrial-1.0.5.1-linux-x64.run`

The first 2 don't work and the 3rd one says 
`Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Help is appreciated.  I'm on 64-bit Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: I think you would be better asking on an Ubuntu forum (or a Sencha forum if there is such a thing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

Open terminal then navigate the directory that those files available and run the following command:

```
$ chmod +x SenchaCompleteTrial-1.0.5.1-linux-x64.run
$ ./SenchaCompleteTrial-1.0.5.1-linux-x64.run
```

Comment: Thank you!  Just curious, what does chmod do?  Why why the + sign?  i see the minus sign used most of the time.

Comment: chmod like windows file attributes which is changing file attributes. When we set `x` attribute, we want to give an execute permission. `+` means giving the permission, `-` means taking the permission.